# Lotusscript Libraries and DRY

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I created a set of Lotusscript libraries for the purpose of reusing it in other Domino applications.

I tried to refactor and take all `Const` declarations (for custom errors) in all libaries and put it in a new library named `CustomErrors`. Error numbers declared here are intended to be generic (e.g. `PARAM_IS_NOTHING`, `DATABASE_NOT_FOUND`, etc.) so that I could `Use` it for all the libraries in the set.

The problem is, when a client code references 2 libraries that use the `CustomErrors` library, a "Public symbol is declared in another module" error shows up.

Here's my question: is there a way to structure Lotusscript libraries so that we can achieve some form of reusability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two separate libraries (tom and jerry, say) that both reference one library 'Custom Errors', and your code (in a form, say) is referring to both tom and jerry, then there  should not be an error.

Sometimes Notes gets confused as to the order of script libraries. Your first friend is 'Tools/Recompile all LotusScript'.

If that doesn't work and you have Teamstudio Configurator, run a change of Use " into use " (which will ensure that all script libraries with dependancies will get recompiled). Sadly, the third-party tool recompiles better than the IBM ones.

As a last, brachial resort, It's well worth re-creating the two libraries that are causing you troubles.

rename tom to tom_old
renname jerry to jerry_old

create from scratch two new scriptlibraries called tom and jerry

paste the content from tom_old into tom (mutatis mutandis for jerry)

(This is assuming you have looked into tom and jerry for any constant which is possibly doubled)

Comment: Thanks! The "Tools/Recompile all LotusScript" button worked. I was scratching my head as to why LotusScript won't optimize the duplicate "Use" statements. If something oddly doesn't work as expected, I'll remember to check if the automatic compiler is "confused."